# How to create a floating button in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I would like to create a **button that floats above the keyboard**, kind of like the **next button in the Airbnb app** (see screenshot below).

I almost found a solution using https://github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory, but there is an invisible wrapper that cannot be clicked through, which is a big issue.

Isn't there an easy way to achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={{ 
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0
  }}
>
  <Text>Yo Press Me!</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Let me know if that works for you!

You may also want to add in "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view" (package from npm) or "KeyboardAvoidingView" (from "react-native") depending on what works best for you.

Comment: That would stick to the bottom of the screen, but not to the keyboard

Comment: Have you tested it? I'm using just that on my app and it works just fine.

Comment: I did. The keyboard moves in front of it

Comment: And you used the KeyboardAvoidingView?

Comment: I use `<KeyboardAwareScrollView>` (from react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view). Where do you put `<TouchableOpacity>`? Inside `<KeyboardAwareScrollView>` ? Outside `<KeyboardAwareScrollView>` ? I've tried different solutions, but nothing does what you say.

Comment: It should go inside the component. I have the hierarchy like <ScrollView><KBASV><View><TO></TO></View></KBASV></ScrollView>. The View has the position absolute and bottom 0. I should also mention that I'm using react-native@0.41.2 and react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@0.2.7

Comment: I tried the `<ScrollView><KBASV><View><TO></TO></View></KBASV></ScrollVie‌​w>` hierarchy, but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing some css. I also tried several solutions using `<KeyboardAvoidingView>`. It's better, but I did not manage to get a perfect result (floating button + scrollable view + autoscroll)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway